# RegEx for multiple newlines with different tags

Tags: regex, regular-language

```
            <p>HISTORY</p>
            <p>1. Vicky Mears 1st dog's owner.</p>
            <p>2. Paul Nash 2nd dog's owner.</p>
            <p>3. Died 39 months of age</p>
            </info>
```

i want to search from starttag HISTORY endtag plus everything in between doesn't matter how many lines and ending with endtag info as stated above.

sorry for my english im new here and very difficult to write my code cause it won't show up i have several edits just to get this right. ~ i guess :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]The following regex will match exactly the content that you have described:

```
(?<=<p>HISTORY</p>)((.*\r\n)+)*(?=</info>)
```

If you need to extract it, you can use the backreference `\1` 
If you use UNIX end of line, you can omit the `\r`

Cheers!

Comment: hey Allan, very helpful. Just what i just needed, thanks.